# Dimension of GL(n,R) vs GL(n,C)

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

We know the dimensions of the following Lie Groups:  $\dim\operatorname{O}(n)=(n^2-n)/2$, $\dim\operatorname{U}(n) = n^2$, $\dim \operatorname{Diag}(n)\cap\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}) = n$, $\dim\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})= n^2$, and $\dim\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{C}) = 2n^2$. When we decompose an invertible real matrix with the SVD $W=U\Lambda V^T\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, we can count the degrees of freedom in W as $(n^2-n)/2$ degrees of freedom for $U\in\operatorname{O}(n)$, $n$ degrees of freedom for $\Lambda\in\operatorname{Diag}(n)\cap\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, and $(n^2-n)/2$ degrees of freedom for $V^T\in\operatorname{O}(n)$. All degrees of freedom added together yields the dimension of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, i.e., $(n^2-n)/2 + n + (n^2-n)/2 = n^2 = \dim\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Intuitively, this makes sense. However in the complex case we have a different story. For a complex invertible matrix $W=U\Lambda V^T\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ decomposed with the SVD, we have $n^2$ degrees of freedom for $U\in U(n)$, $n$ degrees of freedom for $\Lambda\in\operatorname{Diag}(n)\cap\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, and $n^2$ degrees of freedom for $V^T\in U(n)$. If we sum the degrees of freedom we get
$n^2 + n + n^2 = 2n^2 +n > 2n^2 = \dim\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Can someone help me understand why this is so? Is it just coincidence that the degrees of freedom sum up to the dimension of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and not for $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the complex case the SVD has (generically) $n$ dimensions worth of ambiguity, which exactly accounts for the difference between your dimension counts. Namely, even if we normalize the left and right singular vectors to be unit vectors they are still at best (in the case of distinct singular values) unique up to a phase (in the real case they are unique up to a sign).